# How to calculate h for my greenhouse?

Tags: geometry

I'm building a greenhouse with a curved roof. For sake of calculating how much material to buy, I need to find out the value of ***h*** in the diagram below.

Thanks in advance.

[image: Roof of greenhouse]

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question.  What kind of curve is it?  Is it part of a parabola?

Comment: If it is a circular arch, the information is adequate for a (numerical) solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just interested in the value, just look at this [Wikipedia page](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Circular_segment) and look at the formula for arc length.
$$s=\left(h+\frac{c^2}{4h}\right)\arcsin\left(\frac{c}{h+c^2/4h}\right),$$
where $s$ is arc length and $c$ is the lenght of the 'base'.
Plugging in your measurements, we have:
$$13=\left(h+\frac{25}{h}\right)\arcsin\left(\frac{10}{h+25/h}\right).$$

To simplify, we can write it with an extra variable:
$$D=h+25/h$$ (incidentally, this is diameter of the circle from which the arc is "cut out"). Then we need to solve:
$$\sin(13/D)=10/D.$$
Simple numerical tools, as e.g. [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) allow us to calculate that:
$$D\approx 10.6427,\ h\approx 3.5.$$

Comment: Why are you assuming that the curve is part of a circle?

Comment: Because the drawing suggests so ;-)
Moreover, if it is NOT a part of the circle, the problem is hardly tractable. We have no information, what function defines the curve. Part of a circle is at least a good approximation.